# Access VM Ubuntu running application using Hyper-V with host browser

Tags: hyper-v

I got a question about Hyper-v VM capability. I have a Ubuntu VM and inside it, Im running a service locally. I am able to see it and use it within the VM browser. However, I want to be able to use within my host browser. Inside my VM session, I write localhost:8080 and I can access the platform of my program. However, when I try this in my host computer browser, I cant access it.

Is there a way to be able to access the platform using localhost:8080 within my host web browser?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to type the IP address of your Ubuntu VM :8080 ?
like http://ubuntuVM:8080/ or https://192.168.1.22:8080 ? (replace with the correct address/name)

localhost is a loopback address, it redirects to 'self'